# Loading .phased file in r

Tags: r

Is there a way to load [this](http://tau.ac.il/~saharon/StatGen2014/hapmap3_r2_b36_fwd.consensus.qc.poly.chr22_yri.phased) file in r ("load" doesn't work)? I am not familiar with this format and I couldn't find anything online.

Thanks.

Comment: The ordinary `read.table()` seems to do fine (type `?read.table` into your console to get help). (`tmp<-read.table("clipboard",h=T);dim(tmp)` appears to indicate this dataset has 20085 rows and 202 columns - Is that correct?)

Comment: `load` is specifically for .Rdata saved sets.  Your file is pure text, tab-delimited, so... ah fooey being ninja'd as I type.

Comment: @texb, I've got only 103 columns...

Comment: @David Arenburg: The file apparently contains spaces as well as tabs, so he should probably use your parameter choice `sep="\t"` if he considers letter-pairs such as "A A" as individual cell entries (otherwise the sep-default "any whitespace" should disaggregate these)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp <- read.table("http://tau.ac.il/~saharon/StatGen2014/hapmap3_r2_b36_fwd.consensus.qc.poly.chr22_yri.phased", sep = "\t", header = T)
```

Explanation per requests below: If you'll type `?read.table`, you will see that the `file` argument can receive a complete url path (you can type `?url` for further invastiagation).

By running `textConnection("http://tau.ac.il/~saharon/StatGen2014/hapmap3_r2_b36_fwd.consensus.qc.poly.chr22_yri.phased")`

You can see that the connection is open and accesible for R

```
# "\"http://tau.ac.il/~saharon/StatGen2014/hapmap3_r2_b36_fwd.consensus.qc.poly.chr22_yri.phased\"" 
# class 
# "textConnection" 
# mode 
# "r" 
# text 
# "text" 
# opened 
# "opened" 
# can read 
# "yes" 
# can write 
# "no"
```

The `sep` argument in `read.table` is the field separator character. One way to determine how this data is separated is to use `getURL` function in the `Rcurl` package

```
library(RCurl)
txt <- getURL("http://tau.ac.il/~saharon/StatGen2014/hapmap3_r2_b36_fwd.consensus.qc.poly.chr22_yri.phased")
str(txt)
# chr "rsID\tposition_b36\tNA19095_A NA19095_B\tNA19096_A NA19096_B\tNA18867_A NA18867_B\tNA18868_A NA18868_B\tNA18924_A NA18924_B\tNA"| __truncated__
```

You can see the `\t` seperators between the datasets values.

All is left now, is to use base R function `read.table` while using the `\t` separators and indicating that the data set has headers using the `header = T` operator

Comment: He probably doesn't need `RCurl` since presumably he's sitting at the linked location.

Comment: Please consider elaborating on your answer.

Comment: I don't think there is much to elaborate. It's just reading tab separated data with base R function.

Comment: Ok, per your request, see above. Hope it detailed enoguh